# AWS S3 CopyObject keeps cache-control?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm using the .NET SDK to copy objects between two S3 buckets, like so:

```
var request = new CopyObjectRequest
{
    SourceBucket = _sourceBucket,
    SourceKey = objectKey,
    DestinationBucket = _destinationBucket,
    DestinationKey = destinationKey
};
```

I noticed the `Cache-Control` header is present on the *new* image.

I don't want any caching at all on these images (e.g `Cache-Control: private`).

Questions:

1. How did the `Cache-Control` get there? S3 bucket setting, or default behaviour of copy? (more curiousity on my end)
2. How can i ensure the target images aren't cached? (i can't see how to set the `Cache-Control` on the copy)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answers.

1) "*When copying an object, you can preserve all metadata (default) or specify new metadata*.". So this is 'default' behaviour. [ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3_CopyObject.htm)

2)
You can set the headers *after* you construct the object. Note: you need to set *all* headers, since you choose `REPLACE` in the meta data directive.

```
var request = new CopyObjectRequest
{
   MetadataDirective = S3MetadataDirective.REPLACE
};

request.Headers.CacheControl = "private";
request.Headers.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
```